# How to Execute Powershell commands from a Sharepoint Hosted App?

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-addin, visual-studio

So I need to create a Site Inventory(collection of all documents) as an OOTB Sharepoint Feature.

This is the way I thought of doing it.

1. Create a Sharepoint feature in Visual Studio wherein executing the Powershell commands.
2. Deploying the feature in a Sharepoint Hosted App.

I have searched everywhere but I am not getting a proper idea of how to achieve this in Sharepoint 2013.

thanks in advance